# How to test RESTful web service performance

Tags: apache, rest, tornado, performance-testing, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful web service (tornado), including login page, fetch data api, post data api and so on. To fetch or post data, the user need to login in advance. Now I want to test the performance of my service.

I just google it, and find that I can use `Apache Bench` to test. something like：

```
> ab -n 100 -c 10 http://example.com
```

Now I can check the performance of login page, but how to login and test "fetch data api" through `Apache Bench`

Cookie

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

localhost   FALSE   /   FALSE   1436347541  user    "2|1:0|10:1433755541|4:user|4:IjEi|2906a3a418c013247ba2186dbba8f5134b20fc168063d952a3d5    6c1fbf167d63"
```

Comment: How is the information that the user is logged in representen in requests after the login? Is a session cookie set? If yes, set it on `ab` using the `-C` option.

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes, but it's a Netscape HTTP Cookie File, I can't add it to -C directly.

Comment: But it should be possible to write a script to extract the cookie from this file.

Comment: I just updated my question with cookie content, could you help take a look?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your app authenticates users.

If it uses cookies, then the simplest way I can think of is to login to the website in any modern browser, open the browser's Dev Tools and look for the cookie that came back from the server.

Pass that cookie to Apache Benchmark using the `-C` option and have the url as the secure page that you want to test.